# Validating parameters for malicious SQL when building dynamic SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

I have a situation where I must use dynamic SQL as its appearing difficult to use parameters.

The query I will execute dynamically is as below. 
**What is the best way to validate the string in @sql for malicious SQL?** I need to allow valid strings like 'CountryId = 23' but not allow strings like 'delete from Countries'. I do not want everything to be NOT ALLOWED.

I am using C# to run this query against SQL Server 2008 R2.

Perhaps, I could validate at SQL level or at C# level, but I am unsure which would be better.

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT * from Customers 
  where ' + @filterExpression + 
  ' order by ' + @sortExpression;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

**UPDATE:** Maxim's answer seems to be the best for situations where you must use dynamic SQL, though dynamic SQL like the code I have in this post should be avoided as much as possible.

I came up with some validation on the variable  @filterExpression in T-SQL to validate for malicious SQL code, which may still miss some malicious cases, but here is the T-SQL I came up with.

```
IF PATINDEX('%DELETE %',  @filterExpression ) > 0 
  OR PATINDEX('%SELECT %FROM%',  @filterExpression ) > 0 
  OR PATINDEX('%;%',  @filterExpression ) > 0 
  OR PATINDEX('%DROP %',  @filterExpression ) > 0 
  OR PATINDEX('%CREATE %',  @filterExpression ) > 0 
  OR PATINDEX('%TRUNCATE %',  @filterExpression ) > 0 
  OR PATINDEX('%sys%',  @filterExpression ) > 0
  OR PATINDEX('%INDEX %', @filterExpression ) > 0
  OR PATINDEX('%UPDATE %', @filterExpression ) > 0
  OR PATINDEX('%INSERT %',  @filterExpression ) > 0
  OR PATINDEX('%EXEC %',  @filterExpression ) > 0
  OR PATINDEX('%EXECUTE %',  @filterExpression ) > 0
  OR PATINDEX('%CAST%',  @filterExpression ) > 0
  OR PATINDEX('%DECLARE %',  @filterExpression ) > 0
  OR PATINDEX('%CONVERT%',  @filterExpression ) > 0
BEGIN
  RETURN;
END
```

Comment: How did you deduce it is "impossible to use parameters"? It's the same.. but, better.

Comment: I meant, that its not easy to find a parameters based approach in the situation I am coding against and I have tight deadlines for this task. You have some sample code in SQL to validate?

Comment: Easy - `bool IsSlqEneteredByUserMalicious(string sql) { return true;}`... I'd strongly recommend reconsidering design of your tool OR ignoring security issues altogether (which is perfectly fine if user already have admin rights)

Comment: The only way to validate it yourself is to write a full SQL grammar parser. Even then you can't trust it. What seems more suitable for your tight deadline? A SQL grammar parser or parameterized queries?

Comment: What would be the code inside the method IsSlqEneteredByUserMalicious( string sql)?

Comment: @Sunil You missed Alexei's gag. The body of that method is `return true`.. because all SQL entered by a user should be treated as malicious.

Comment: Ok. But then all valid strings will also be malicious. I want valid strings to pass through.

Comment: I am trying to find a parameters based approach, and hope I can do so by tomorrow, since my deadline is end of tomorrow.

Comment: You have 3 choices. There's the right way.. the wrong way.. and ignoring it altogether. The thing is.. the wrong way is actually going to take you 30000 times longer than the right way. Ignoring security issues is also an option.. and that is instant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could use a read only user, this would at least block any
   updates.
2. Look for keywords that look suspicious to you: INSERT,
   UPDATE, etc.
3. Use third-party libraries like [this](http://www.dpriver.com/blog/anti-sql-injection-tool/)

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev) is the good bunch of anti injections techniques.

Comment: Maxim - Thanks for the answer. I like the approach 1, where I would use a readonly userid in SQL Server  connection string, and approach 3 also seems nice, which I am looking into now.